# How do I query most recent date in a table that's been converted from BIGINT format?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains one or more entries for each user by date.  The format of the date field is in BIGINT format.  I’m able to convert the date into a readable format using “DATEADD(SS, CONVERT(BIGINT, Create_Date__c), '19700101')” however, I also need to retrieve only the most recent date for each user. Everything I’ve found indicates you can’t use the MAX function with a DATEADD function.  Is there another command?  I’m using SQL Server 17.9.1.

Comment: Did you **try** using `MAX` in conjunction with `DATEADD`? What did you find? If an error what was the code and error message?

Comment: While having a function calling another function is not a good practice, it should still work. Another alternative would be to put all the converted data into a temp table and then use that temp table to get your data. Depending on the size of your table, this could be quite a poor performing query either way and may be bad enough to consider changing the format to a datetime or date data type.

Comment: You can insert all the data into temp table with user and date with date format instead of BIGINT and then use max function.

Comment: You can create a CTE that creates a column with the converted date, and then select from THAT using MAX() and I think that should work. But it'll be slow if there are tons of rows to deal with, because it's basically an unindexed table-scan on a computed virtual column.

Answer (score 1):

Those dates are unix dates...encoded as the number of seconds since 1/1/1970. You sure don't need to convert them to dates to figure out which are the most recent ones. You can select the most-recent dates and users as keys of a virtual table...and then join that to the original table:

```
select 
  dateadd( ss, orig.[date], '19700101' ) as realDate,
  --> other stuff you need here...
from 
(
  select 
    [user], 
    max( Create_Date__c ) [date]
  from 
    someTable 
  group by 
    [user]
) as recent
inner join
someTable orig
on
  recent.[user] = orig.[user]
  and
  recent.[date] = orig.Create_Date__c
```

BTW, and if you're wondering, I put the [user] and [date] column names in brackets because they're reserved words.

Comment: Glad it got you there ;-)